# Fastapi Upload a Image

Tags: python, html, cordova, fastapi

i try to upload a image to a fastapi from a Cordova Webapp and get the following error:

```
{"detail":[{"loc":["body","terms"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"},{"loc":["body","privacy"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}

INFO:     192.168.1.129:51915 - "POST /upload/ HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity
```

My FastApi Code is:

```
@app.post("/upload/", dependencies=[Depends(valid_content_length)])
async def create_upload_file(file: bytes = File(...), terms: str = Form(...), privacy: str = Form(...)):
    allowedFiles = {"image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif", "image/tiff", "image/bmp", "video/webm"}
    if file.content_type in allowedFiles:
        filename = str(uuid.uuid4())
        with open("uploaded_images" + filename + file.filename, "wb") as buffer:
            shutil.copyfileobj(file.file, buffer)
        return {"filename": file.filename}
    else:
        return "miau"
```

Client Code:

```
<form method="post" action="http://192.168.1.129:8080/upload">

                <div class="form_row">
                    <label for="myfile">Choose your image:</label>
                    <input type="file" id="myfile" name="file">
                </div>
                <div class="form_row">

                        <label>Accept:</label>
                        <label class="label-checkbox item-content">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="my-checkbox" value="privacy" required>
                            <div class="item-media">
                                <i class="icon icon-form-checkbox"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item-inner">
                                <div class="item-title"><a src="" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a></div>
                            </div>
                        </label>

                        <label class="label-checkbox item-content">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="my-checkbox" value="terms" required>
                            <div class="item-media">
                                <i class="icon icon-form-checkbox"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item-inner">
                                <div class="item-title">Terms of Use</div>
                            </div>
                        </label>
                        <label class="label-checkbox item-content">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="form_submit" id="submit" value="Send"/>
                        </label>
                </div>
            </form>
```

How to solve the problem? According to error the body is empty, but I don't know what the problem is.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

The error says pretty much everything

```
"loc":["body","terms"],"msg":"field required"
```

and

```
"loc":["body","privacy"],"msg":"field required"
```

This means that your form is not submitting the `terms` and the `privacy` fields.

If you look at your `HTML` code, you can see that both of the inputs have the name `my-checkbox`, while `fastapi` route expects two parameters: `privacy` and `terms`.

Change the names of the inputs to match the two parameters

Comment: Thank you. Played around a bit too much :D

The upload works, but as soon as I switch to file: UploadFile = File(...) it comes: {"detail":[{"loc":["body", "file"], "msg": "Expected UploadFile, received: <class 'str'>", "type": "value_error"}]}

Comment: had to add enctype="multipart/form-data" to form